How could our "Off-Topic close reasons" be improved? What would be another useful one?
We currently have three Off-Topic Close Reasons:


This question does not appear to be about Bitcoin within the scope defined in the help center. (Default Off-Topic Close Reason)

Questions on current market values, energy costs or service provider availability are off-topic as the answers are changing too frequently to be useful to others.

Questions seeking product or service recommentadations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.



We can have three Custom Close Reasons, so there would be room for one more. Moderators can edit these, so if you have some ideas how they could be improved, I'd be interested in hearing suggestions.
One thing that I might want to fold into the third one, the one banning recommendations, would be that "requesting service reviews" is off-topic as well. What do you think about that?

I have suggested improving

Questions seeking product or service recommentadations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

to 

Questions seeking product recommendations or service reviews are off-topic because they tend to become outdated quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

but it is waiting for another moderator to confirm it.

Is there enough space for?:

Questions regarding the legal side of the use of Bitcoin are off-topic as the answers depending on the local jurisdiction are unlikely to be helpful to others

Law question come very often.

We'd have to axe one of the other custom reasons to make room. It might be a good time to improve them, though.

I created a new discussion here: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1059/5406
