Revisit close reasons in 2021
MCCCS brought up in the 2014 discussion 'How could our “Off-Topic close reasons” be improved? What would be another useful one?' whether we could add another close reason regarding legal questions. We cannot, since we're at the limit, but we could rewrite, remove or improve one of the existing close reasons, or just start over from the scratch.
This is what we currently have:

What would the best three custom close reasons be for us in 2021? Please share your thoughts what can go, how things could be changed, and what should get improved.

I've always thought that the 'service provider availability' reason for close is perhaps better grouped with the 'product or service reviews' category. There have been a number of times I've seen Qs that ride the line between these two closing categories end up with a bunch of votes split between the two.
Perhaps reword the second to 'product or service availability and reviews'?

Would you perhaps like to provide a concrete proposal of what the three close reasons would look like after your changes are applied?
